# Return AJAX view response to blade

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, redirect, laravel-blade

Working on Laravel. I have an AJAX call that sends a variable from the login page to a controller that renders and returns a **view (pages.tasks3)**. It's working fine but returning the view to a **div (postRequestData)** in the login page.

How can i modify the response to **redirect to (pages.tasks3) view instead of posting the view in a div?**

**AJAX**:

```
function register() {
    var testemail = email;
    $.post('maram', { fullemail:testemail}, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(testemail);

        $('#postRequestData').html(data);

    })
}
```

**Controller return**:

```
$html = view('pages.tasks3')->with(compact('tasks','elementCount'))->render();
return $html;
```

**Login Blade:**

```
<div id="postRequestData">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can't "redirect to a view." A view is something Laravel uses to render HTML. You can redirect to a URL of your application like `/pages/tasks/3` using Javascript in your AJAX call. Laravel can then route that URL to a `Controller` that returns the `pages.tasks3` view. When a `Controller` returns a view, Laravel will automatically render and send the HTML to be rendered on the page.

Comment: This makes sense, but when i do it this way i get **ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: tasks**

Comment: That's probably because of the `with(compact('tasks','elementCount'))` in your code, which may not exist as a local variable in your `Controller` yet.

Comment: They exist and return a correct value to the div in the login page. I get these values using an api call in the controller, but then when i redirect it's like i didn't make the call.

Comment: Okay, hm, I'm not sure without seeing the `Controller` code. It may have to do with it depending on the `{ fullemail:testemail}` AJAX input, which won't be available when it's called after redirection. You could try using `Session::flash()` if you're just trying to pass along something to render to the user once.

Comment: This is the part of the code i need to return `$tasks = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
$elementCount  = count($tasks['todo-items']);` I'm not sure if i can use session for that or how to do that